# After drag and drop Recyclerview item, how can I provide the updated Position of a list item at onbind method of an adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an application in which I fetching data from a database to `Recyclerview`. I am changing the recyclerview item's position by drag and drop, and at time of drag and drop I am getting an updated `ArrayList` and inserting into `Sqlite`.

I also delete item on left swap. The problem occurs when I delete item after drag and drop. After drag/drop, the item's new position is not getting at delete function. You will understand this problem better after going through the code.

**Code of Adapter's onbind**: I am posting only problem related code

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyContactHolder myContactHolder, final int i) {


        Log.e("poistionINAdapter:", String.valueOf(i));

        myContactHolder.DeleteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                removeflag=true;
                customDataListModels.notify();
                customDataListModels.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                notifyItemChanged(i, customDataListModels.size());
                Log.e("removeItem", String.valueOf(customDataListModels.toString()));
                reCustom=customDataListModels;

                if (removeflag == true) {
                    tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.deleteall();
                    for (int i = 0; i < reCustom.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e("chname", String.valueOf(reCustom.get(i).getName()));
                        tempinsert(reCustom.get(i).getName(), reCustom.get(i).getNumber(), reCustom.get(i).getColor(), reCustom.get(i).getFSize(), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**Code at drag and drop stuff:** this is also inside the adapter

```
 @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(customDataListModels, i, i + 1);

            }
//            Log.e("UpTODown", String.valueOf(toPosition));
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(customDataListModels, i, i - 1);

            }
//            Log.e("DownToUp", String.valueOf(toPosition));
        }

            Log.e("postion", "from pos : "+String.valueOf(fromPosition)+" : to Position :"+String.valueOf(toPosition));

        mListChangedListener.onNoteListChanged(customDataListModels);

        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

        chCustom=customDataListModels;
        if (swapChecker == true) {
            tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.deleteall();
            for (int i = 0; i < chCustom.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("PositionInSwap", String.valueOf(chCustom.get(i).getName()));
                tempinsert(chCustom.get(i).getName(), chCustom.get(i).getNumber(), chCustom.get(i).getColor(), chCustom.get(i).getFSize(), 1);
                customDataListModels=chCustom;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see, at drag and drop I am deleting the whole table of `sqlite` and inserting a new updated `arraylist`, at the same time as deleting the item.

As I mentioned, the problem occurs after drag and drop. When I delete after drag and drop, it's deleting the old position item. So how can I provide a new position after drag and drop at onbind?

If you require any more code or screen shots, ask me and I will post them.

Comment: Can you add in the class and methods you use to save your data in the database? Also your data object class chCustom.

Comment: I updated post but that's not problem I am reading database at every event , and it's totally fine, problem is not getting updated position after drag/drop

Comment: The issue as far as I can guess is with your RecyclerView still having a previous dataset and hence old positions instead of newer ones after swipe. I had a somewhat similar issue and I fixed it by reattaching my adapter after swipe. I have an open sourced project you can look at with drag-drop and swipe to delete recyclerview - https://github.com/mdnaseemashraf/Memento2 Look into TaskActivity.java's resetAdapter().

Comment: Your answer is on the spot thank you , that was great lead .

Comment: I'll change my comment to answer. Please accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue as far as I can guess is with your RecyclerView still having a previous dataset and hence old positions instead of newer ones after swipe.

I had a somewhat similar issue and I fixed it by **reattaching my adapter after swipe**.

I have an open sourced project you can look at with drag-drop and swipe to delete recyclerview, [here](https://github.com/mdnaseemashraf/Memento2). Look into TaskActivity.java's resetAdapter().

**resetAdapter method**:

```
public void resetAdapter(){
    mAdapter = new TasksAdapter(taskList,TaskActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,taskList.size());
}
```